# Minus/hyphen in table name in SQL query

Tags: ms-access

I just realized that my SQL statements containing minus sign "-" in table names are executed without error. 
For example:

```
SELECT * from MYTAB-10;
SELECT * from MYTAB-9;
```

also using adodb objects:

```
rst.Open "MYTAB-10",conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

...while I don't have table called MYTAB-10, just MYTAB. I'm  really surprised, as never heard about any operators in table name written like this. 
Number of rows in both versions (with -, and without), and regardless number at the end is the same, so what really is happening here?
I didn't found any information about it so far. 
Is there any rationale behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access automatically interprets a word break before `-`

This means:

```
SELECT * from MYTAB-10
```

Is equivalent to the following queries

```
SELECT * FROM MYTAB -10 -- Space added
SELECT * from [MYTAB] AS [-10] -- Explicit alias to make meaning more clear
```

This also means you could write the following

```
SELECT [-10].SomeField FROM MYTAB-10 INNER JOIN MYTAB-11 ON [-10].SomeField = [-11].AnotherField
```

As ADO automatically adds `SELECT * FROM` if you just provide a table name, that's equivalent.

However: NEVER use this. This behavior hasn't been standardized, and will make your code nonportable as other RDBMSes will syntax error on it.

Also note that this doesn't work in ADO when directly opening a table instead of using an auto-generated SQL statement:

```
Set rst = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("MYTAB-10", Options := adCmdTableDirect)
'Errors: cannot find input table or query MYTAB-10
```

Also note: the `+` character exhibits similar behavior. However, `\`, `:` and `*` do not.